# in a table want to include sale price but it inserts into a new cell and not the same

Tags: php, html, css

I'm not actually using a table i'm using a list but formatting it like a table but I'm having an issue where I want to include a sale price and an original price in the same cell but if I put them in div's it splits them up into two cells.

```
       for($z =0; $z < 4; $z++ )
                {
                     if($i+$z >= count($varProduct))
                     {  break;} 
                    if ($varProduct[$z+$i][11] > 0)
                    {
                    echo                  
                    '<div class = "salePrice"> SALE $' . $varProduct[$z+$i][11] . '&nbsp; </div>' . '<div class ="originalPrice"> $' . $varProduct[$z+$i][2] . '</div>'
                    ;   
                    }                       
                }
```

I thought since it was one echo it would be one cell but it's adding two is there a way to get around that?

edit: my.css

```
.originalPrice{
font-size:14px;
float:left;
color:black;
text-decoration: line-through;
width:317px;
margin-right:0px;
margin-left:0px;
text-align: center;
margin-bottom:20px;

}
.salePrice{
font-size:14px;
float:left;
color:red;
width:317px;
margin-right:0px;
margin-left:0px;
text-align: center;
margin-bottom:20px;


}
```

Comment: I tried putting the </div> at the end and that sort of works but they don't display:inline-block they're a break

Comment: The code you have posted generates a sequence of `<div>`. Where are these 'cells'?

Comment: I said "
I'm not actually using a table i'm using a list but formatting it like a table"

Comment: Yes I read that and it made no sense before. Repeating it hasn't helped.

Comment: how do you define `$i` ?

Comment: it's nested loop I defined it in a higher for statement It didn't seem like it's relative to the code I call a loop that iterates to make 4x in colums in a singlw row so then the higher loop to will make one row at a time It's kind of a table inside a table u got 3 elements that are grouped price pic and name but they need to be added in their own table  and go in the correct order

Comment: if i had said LIST instead of TABLE would that have made it better? I didn't think it was a big deal

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your CSS you should have something like:

```
.salePrice { display:inline-block; }

.originalPrice{ display:inline-block; }
```

If you are formatting it "as a table", it may desired to supply a width or some padding inside of the CSS of each DIV element, to give it an easier-to-read appearance to the user.

You could also do this with inline attributes (should you choose against most common practice):

```
 for($z =0; $z < 4; $z++ )
                {
                     if($i+$z >= count($varProduct))
                     {  break;} 
                    if ($varProduct[$z+$i][11] > 0)
                    {
                    echo                  
                    '<div class = "salePrice" style="display:inline-block;"> SALE $' . $varProduct[$z+$i][11] . '&nbsp; </div>' . '<div class ="originalPrice;" style="display:inline-block"> > $' . $varProduct[$z+$i][2] . '</div>'
                    ;   
                    }       


            }
```

If you choose to use floats, you also can float div elements.

```
.salePrice { float:left; }

.originalPrice{ float:left; }
```

just make sure you use a float:clear; within the CSS of the last element.

Comment: I tried using floats and display-inline neither work they could the 2nd item in the echo as if it was a new echo

Comment: Did you specify a width to .salePrice and .originalPrice ? Try giving them a width of 100px each just to see the outcome and see what happens.

Comment: yeah that's probably it!

Comment: A div by default will fill it's parent container completely in width. If you don't specify a width to an inline-block element, it will render like a standard block element, filling the width of it's parent element.